# Почему SQLite требует столбец, которого у меня нет?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть такая SQLite-таблица:

[image: SQLite-таблица]

В неё я пытаюсь добавить объекты такого типа:

```
public class Ticket : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Ticket()
    {

    }
    public Ticket(Ticket ticket) : this(ticket.Number, ticket.Question, ticket.Answers)
    {

    }
    public Ticket(int number, string question, ObservableCollection<TicketAnswer> answers)
    {
        Number = number;
        Question = question;
        Answers = answers;
    }
    private int number;
    [Key]
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
        set
        {
            number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }
    private string question;
    public string Question
    {
        get
        {
            return question;
        }
        set
        {
            question = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Question");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TicketAnswer> Answers { get; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

И при попытке добавить объект такого типа выскакивает следующее:
[image]

Как видно по моей модели у меня нет никакого свойства `Discriminator`. Почему же тогда для SQLite оно существует?

Comment: Дело в наследовании - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7393788/3768545
Коротко - для отличия одного наследника от другого требуется специальная колонка.

Comment: @Monk, получается мне нужно создать этот столбец в таблице?

Comment: Да. Насколько помню, должен подойти условный nvarchar(max), но лучше почитать доки EF, что он туда пишет, может как-то сконфигурировать это дело.

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал не пытаться сохранять в БД классы VM напрямую. Для работы с БД используйте отдельные классы и мэпинг для преобразования их в/из VM классы.